# In github markdown, how do I show a link to the current repo?

Tags: github

Sometimes I fork a github repository and want to be able to include in the README a bit that says

**Clone the repo**:
`git clone [URL FOR THIS REPOSITORY]`

How do I do that in a way that always inserts the correct URL? I don't want to hard code it because I later want to merge my fork back with the original.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.  Most of the examples and notes provided in the [Basic writing and formatting syntax](https://help.github.com/articles/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax/) help section discuss how GitHub will automatically parse certain text and link to what it is describing, but none of the notes say that it will transform the actual text.  Why add that bit anyway?  It's already displayed when a user clicks the "Clone or Download" button at the top of the page.

Comment: Why add it? Because I want to give a complete description of how to use my project for people who may not have experience with using git or github.